# How can i get the headers request from client side for sockets using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am quite new to this thing. I just wanted to know if it is possible to get the web sockets client side request header. 
I'm using in the server side node.js:

- Using ExpresJS I can get headers like:

  ```
  router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
      console.log(req.headers);
  ```

  });
- Using Web Socket, its possible?

  ```
  var WebSocket = require('ws');
  var ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/path');
  ws.on('open', function open() {
       // how to get the headers
       ws.send('something');
  });
  ```

It is possible?
Thanks

Comment: Websockets don't have headers (other than a protocol), that's sort of the point, no extra bytes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebSockets don't have headers, but their upgrade requests do.

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

  console.log(ws.upgradeReq.headers);

  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});
```

Note you can't set headers as part of the ws request.

Comment: When we use "new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/path')" to connect to a websocket server, is there a way to pass a header that could then be retrieved within the upgrade request ?