# How can I get headers?

Tags: node.js

I have websocket client:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://adressOfSomeWebsocketServer:8080');
ws.on('open', function() {
    console.log('connected');
    ws.send('someCoolStuff');
});
```

Some info server send in headers, so I need handshake response headers - is it possible to get them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get the headers request from client side for sockets using NodeJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726003/how-can-i-get-the-headers-request-from-client-side-for-sockets-using-nodejs)

Comment: No, it's not, because i have just websocket client.

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution - just print out object after successful connect to server:

```
ws.on('open', function() {
    console.log('connected');
    console.log( util.inspect( ws, {depth:null} ) );
});
```